# Helping understanding equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Reading a script I have found the following equation:

$$x'(t)=f(t,x(t),p) \\   
x(t_{0})=x_{0} $$

where $p$ is a parameter for which:

$$\frac{d}{dp}\frac{d}{dt}x(t,p0)=\frac{d}{dp} f(t,x(t,p_0),p_0)=\frac{d}{dx}f(t,x(t,p_0),p_0)\cdot\frac{d}{dp}x(t,p0)+\frac{d}{dp}f(t,x(t,p_0),p_0)$$

I understand the first equation, but I have no idea what happens next. Can someone explain this?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Exactly which part don't you understand and what is confusing you? This seems like a simple application of the chain rule and using the fact that $$\frac{d}{dt} x(t,p_{0}) = x'(t,p_{0}) = f(t,x(t,p_{0}),p_{0})$$ Though if $p_{0}$ is a fixed parameter value, I would have thought $\frac{d}{dp} g(p_{0}) = 0$.

Comment: The r.h.s. of the last equation should be written in terms of partial derivatives: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x(t,p),p)\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial p}x(t,p)+\frac{\partial}{\partial p}f(t,x(t,p),p).$$ Moreover, as the derivative is taken with respect to $p$, the parameter should be $p$ and not $p_0$.

Comment: It's fine now :) I had spontaneous brain freeze.